# Pass date from javascript via php to mysql

Tags: php

I have a Date in this form in JavaScript: "10.02.2010".

I Pass it via url to php, together with other variables.

Then I convert it in php to a php-Date like this:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == "TPopMassnDatum") {
        if ($value) {
            $value = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($value));
        } else {
            $value = null;
        }
    } 
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
$value = date_create_from_format('d.m.Y', $value);
```

Because there are several other values and I need to insert, I implode the keys:

```
$Feldliste = implode(",", array_keys($_GET));
```

then implode the values:

```
$Wertliste = '"'.implode('","', array_values($_GET)).'"';
```

then run this query:

```
$Querystring = 'INSERT INTO tblTeilPopMassnahme ('.$Feldliste.') VALUES ('.$Wertliste.')';
```

The date field in mysql is datetime.

My problem: The dates, as they arrive in mysql, are usually off. For example: 20.04.2006 instead of 20.12.2012.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, your foreach is totally useless, just use `$_GET['TPopMassnDatum']`

Comment: the field in your database have to be date type of field not varchar or char or anything else

Comment: You're also asking for a SQL injection attack by building your SQL query string directly from untrusted data, and neither running through a sanitization function nor using parameterized queries.

Comment: @shnisaka: the field in mysql is of type datetime. Should that better be date? Would that make a difference?

Comment: @shnisaka: I'll have to follow your hints and find out what sanitization functions and parameterized queries are. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

First of all the field format for mysql datetime is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, that might be why its giving you weird times.
Also if there is only a date, why are you using datetime instead of just date?

Also, have you echo'd $value before you put it in? it might be converting it funny because there is no time to begin with. check the value of $vaule before you insert it.

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS unfortunately does not help

Comment: the value echoed before $value = date("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS", strtotime($value)) is correct. Afterwards it is wrong

Comment: the format in mysql is now date. Unfortunately the problem remains

Comment: I'm using this now: `$value = date("YYYY-MM-DD", strtotime($value));`, as this is now the format in mysql